# Unity quaterion rotatetoward()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Right now, I am working on the Unity camera for first person view using mouse.
Camera is suppose to move toward to direction of mouse.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

namespace input
{
    public class CameraControl : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private GameObject player;
        [SerializeField] private float speed = 20f;

        float xRotation;
        float yRotation;

        private InputAction cameraAction;
      
        public void Initialize(InputAction cameraAction)
        {
            
            this.cameraAction = cameraAction;
            this.cameraAction.Enable();
        }

        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            Vector2 camera = cameraAction.ReadValue<Vector2>();
          
            float mouseX = camera.x;
            float mouseY = camera.y;

            xRotation -= mouseY;
            yRotation += mouseX;

            Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);

            //Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(30, 30, 0);
            //Debug.Log(goalRotation);
            //Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, goalRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
            //transform.rotation = goalRotation;
            player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, 0);
            
        }
    }

}
```

In the code, I am trying to understand how Quaternion.RotateToward() is working. RotateToward is having tree parameters: target from, target to, and speed of rotation.
Target from is current roation of camera. Target to is rotation that camera should rotate.

So, in the code, from the inputAction, I am receiving the Vector2 x and y values from mouse.
For example, if I move the mouse only to the right value would be like (1.0, 0) (2.0) ...
and if I move the mouse to upward (0, 1.0) (0.3)... Then, when I move the mouse diagnal, (1.0 1.0)..

So, using the Quaternion.RotateToward() actually rotate to the point that I want. However, problem is that it is not rotating based on the speed that I set which is 20f.

I know using

```
transform.rotation = goalRotation;
```

is eaier way to solve rather than use RotateToward(), however, I want to learn how this function should be working.

Any idea about this?

Comment: 20f means 20 degrees per second, a very slow speed (you need 9 secs to turn from left to right), is it your intent?

Comment: `However, problem is that it is not rotating based on the speed that I set which is 20f.` I doubt that .. `Quaternion.RotateTowards` has been there for years and always does what it is supposed to .. -> the problem is not in that function but either in your settings or expectations ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

speed * Time.deltaTime to speed ables to solve the problem